# Comparison of a string with an integer

Tags: python

This program is graphing values ​of sensors obtained from a database in MySQL. I am trying to send an email only if the value that comes from the database is bigger than 25 but sends me the error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

My question is how to make the condition so that it sends the mail taking the value that comes from the database ('value').

**This is the code:**

```
def update_graph(dark_theme):
    dataSQL = []
    X = deque(maxlen=10)    
    Y = deque(maxlen=10)

    sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DB')
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT value, timestamp FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        dataSQL.append(list(row))
        labels = ['value','timestamp']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
        X = df['timestamp']
        Y = df['value']

    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=list(X),
        y=list(Y),
        name='TEMP',
        mode='lines+markers'
    )

    if (df['value'] > 25):
        email = 'email@gmail.com'
        password = 'pass'
        send_to_email = 'email2@gmail.com'
        subject = 'ALERT'
        message = 'Alert'
        file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\p.jpg'

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = send_to_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

        filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
        attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        "attachment;filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
        server.quit()

    return {
        'data': [data],
        'layout' : go.Layout(title="TEMPERATURA",
                             xaxis={'title':'HORA/FECHA'},
                             yaxis={'title':'°C'})
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: First convert the string to an int. `int()` helps here.

Comment: As Michael mentioned, it looks like you are trying to compare a string to an integer. From what I can tell, `df['value']` is supposed to be a string (I'm guessing it is a number that is a string - although this doesn't look like it is the correct syntax). You will want to convert this value to an integer or float by using `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: Please fix code indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your Temperature values to float:

```
Y = df['value'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use convertion from string to float:
`if (float(df['value']) > 25):`

Answer (score 0):

To fix your Error, you need to convert the string from your Database to an integer. Try:

```
if (int(df['value']) > 25):
```